# In my Android apk, ANSYNC TASK method is not working

Tags: android

In my Android apk, I am using async task method.
It was working fine from last many years but now it is creating problem.

**doinbackground()** and **postExecute()** methods are not working (they are not called)
, only preExecute() method is working.
**doinbackground()** and **postExecute()** methods are not working (they are not called)
, only preExecute() method is working.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, ConversationModel, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        heading.setText("myheading");
    }
    });


    try {

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (ConversationModel model : dataList) {

    if (flagStop)
        break;

    publishProgress(model);

    long_time = Long.parseLong(model.sound_time) * 1000 + 500;

    try {

        Thread.sleep(long_time);
        Thread.sleep(long_extraTime);
        long_extraTime = 0;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    i++;
    Log.d("i", i + " -----------------");

    }

    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(ConversationModel... model) {

    if (i % 2 == 0) {

    View v = View.inflate(Conversation1.this, arrInt_resource[0], null);
    v.setAnimation(null);

    TextView txtV_spn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_spn);
    TextView txtV_eng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_eng);
    ImageView img_sound = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgsound_conv_spn2eng);
    RelativeLayout speak_layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.speaking_layout);
    heading.setText(dataList.get(0).heading);
    if (flag != 1) {
        txtV_spn.setText(model[0].eng_txt);
        txtV_eng.setText(model[0].spn_txt);


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (i >= dataList.size()) {
    Log.d("i", i + " ------------------");
    makingcontinueImageView();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code with me, or you have any proof for this issue because we can't judge what you doing wrong in your code.

Comment: can you share the code , without cant tell what went wrong

Comment: I am sharing my code plz check and reply @NidhinPrathap

Comment: I am share our code plz check and reply @KishanDonga

Answer (score 0):

Change .execute() method of asynctask with this one

```
asynctask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```